Quadratic Normal form and basis of the normal form
Given a coordinate matrix of a quadratic form in canonical form:
$$ H =\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}  $$
it's possible to obtain normal form via the formula $H_{norm} = C^THC$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt5} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt5} 
\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
My question is, what will the basis of the normal form be? I am inclined to say that it will contain the columns of matrix C, is this correct?
I am doubtful in this conclusion for a reason: the basis will only contain 3 vectors instead of 4.
